# Get max in a ListBuffer of Some[Long] in Scala

Tags: scala, max, scala-option, listbuffer

This piece of code works fine and returns 343423 as expected:

```
val longList: ListBuffer[Long] = ListBuffer(103948,343423,209754)
val maxLong = longList.max
```

But it doesn't work for Some[Long]:

```
val longSomeList: ListBuffer[Some[Long]] = ListBuffer(Some(103948),Some(343423),Some(209754))
val maxSomeLong = longSomeList.max
```

> Error: No implicit Ordering defined for Some[Long].
>       val maxSomeLong = longSomeList.max

Is there any simple solution to get the max of the second list?

*max function from TraversableForwarder(scala.collection.generic)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `.flatten`.

```
 longSomeList.flatten.max
```

Or give it the ordering to use explicitly:

```
 longSomeList
   .max(Ordering.by[Option[Int], Int](_.getOrElse(Int.MinValue)))
```

Also, don't use mutable collections.

Answer (score 2):

In which real world scenario would you have a `ListBuffer[Some[Long]]`? You could just as well have a `ListBuffer[Long]` then.

This works:

```
val longSomeList: ListBuffer[Option[Long]] = ListBuffer(Some(103948),Some(343423),Some(209754))
val maxSomeLong = longSomeList.max
```

Comment: I had a json file, which is parsed to list of *Some[Long]*. You are right, it works for *Option[Long]*. This is so confusing :D I need to study some basics.

Comment: Which library parses it to a `Some[Long]`? If you statically know it's always going to be a `Some` it doesn't make sense to have the extra level of boxing.

Comment: I used *parseFull* from *scala.util.parsing.json._* and it doesn't make sense to always get *Some*. Do you have any suggestion in your mind?

Comment: I'm no expert in the JSON parsing domain, but I think scala.util.parsing.json is a deprecated API because it was never really meant for production usage.

Answer (score 1):

```
longSomeList.collect { case Some(n) => n }.max
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are trying to order elements of type `Some[Long]`, which is not defined. So you are telling the compiler to know how to order these:

```
scala> Some(1) < Some(2)
<console>:8: error: value < is not a member of Some[Int]
              Some(1) < Some(2)
                      ^
```

What you can do is either unwrap the `Some`s to get the `Long`s

```
longSomeList.flatten.max
```

or to define your implicit ordering likewise:

```
implicit object Ord extends Ordering[Some[Long]] {
  def compare(a: Some[Long], b: Some[Long]) = a.getOrElse(Long.MinValue) compare b.getOrElse(Long.MinValue)
}
```

and then:

```
scala> longSomeList.max
res12: Some[Long] = Some(343423)
```